UIHostingController rootView causing retain cycle
Im stuck with retain cycle caused by usage of UIHostingController.
In memory graph I can clearly see that there is retain cycle(image provided) and I dont know how to break it.
Also to mention MemberTraingDetailsComponent view property is added to Screen using screen.view.addSubview(memberTrainingDetailsComponent.view)
class MemberTrainingDetailsComponent:  DefaultHostingController<DetailsSectionView<MemberDetailsSection>> {
     required init(parent: ContainerComponent?) {
         super.init(rootView: DetailsSectionView<MemberDetailsSection>(parentComponent: parent, viewModel: TrainingTagComponentViewModel(screen: parent as? Screen)))
    }

    @MainActor required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

here is DefaultHostingController subclass:
class DefaultHostingController<Content>: UIHostingController<Content>, HostingScreen where Content: View {
    required init(parent: ContainerComponent?) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    static var size: CGSize {
        .zero
    }

    override init(rootView: Content) {
        super.init(rootView: rootView)
    }
}

Memory graph screenshot showing retain cycle:

Memory graph screenshot showing objects causing retain cycle:

I dont know why _view and host keeps strong references to each other. I also want to know where and when is rootView added inside UIHostingController view property.
Edit:
Here is my DetailSectionView
struct DetailsSectionView<Builder: DetailsSectionListBuilder>: View {
    var data: ComponentData?
    unowned let parentComponent: ContainerComponent?
    @StateObject var viewModel: DetailsSectionViewDataSource

    init(data: ComponentData? = nil, parentComponent: ContainerComponent?, viewModel: DetailsSectionViewDataSource) {
        self.data = data
        self.parentComponent = parentComponent
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(Builder.getAllCases(Builder.self), id: \.id) { content in
            Section {
                content.returnView(data: data, parent: parentComponent, viewModel: viewModel)
            }
}

